# Member variables initialization

Tags: c++, constructor, initialization

Is there any difference regarding the initialization of the `x` member variable in these cases:

```
struct A {
    int x;
    A() {}
};

struct B {
    int x;
    B() : x(0) {}
};

struct C {
    int x;
    C() : x() {}
};
```

For all these cases, in the tests I did, `x` is always set to the initial value of 0. Is this a guaranteed behavior? Is there any difference in these approaches?

Comment: `A::x` is uninitialized. [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7e1e9885623dc23b).

Comment: *in the tests I did, x is always set to the initial value of 0* -- You can't do tests like this and conclude this is how C++ works.  The value of `0` is just as uninitialized as any other value.  You know a value is initialized by following the rules of initialization, which `B` and `C` do successfully.

Comment: `struct A { int x = 0; /*...*/ }` might be interesting to compare...

Comment: *"You can't do tests like this and conclude"* @PaulMcKenzie: That's why OP ask question ;-) That kind of test is a first step, which might reject some hypothesis though.

Comment: Note: Simple tests for behaviour like this can easily be misleading. Do not use zero. It is too often a default filler value. For example, a program starting and clearing all of its initial memory to 0 is not uncommon. If you don't give the program a work out before running the test you'll likely get exactly the number, 0, you expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For `B::B()`, `x` is [direct-initialized](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization) as `0` explicitly in member initializer list.

For `C::C()`, `x` is [value-initialized](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization), as the result [zero-initialized](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization) as `0` in member initializer list.

On the other hand, `A::A()` does nothing. Then for objects of type `A` with automatic and dynamic storage duration, `x` will be [default-initialized](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization) to indeterminate value, i.e. not guaranteed to be `0`. (Note that static and thread-local objects get [zero-initialized](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization).)